# How to pause the activity?

Tags: android

I want to pause the "Event Thread"/ activity as soon as the user does some action(long click for example), and unpause it when user does some other action(simple click). The problem is, after i do a long click, The event thread goes in the waiting queue. SO when a do a simple click, that is not intercepted. How do I achieve this? please note, i do not want to pause the activity by showing some progress dialog etc., i want to retain my activity in foreground and get paused.here is what i have tried :/

```
 final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                 synchronized(this){    
                     try {
                         this.notify();
                         } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 }
            }
        });
      vg.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            try {
                 synchronized(this){    
                     this.wait();
                     }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
      vg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public  void onClick(View v) {
             synchronized(this){    
                 t.start();}
        }

    });
```

Comment: All Ui events happen in one thread, so calling wait on that thread will cause all events to be waiting in the queue. Hence your app will enter a deadlock. I don't see any way of making this work.

Comment: @userSeven7s : I think I would not call that a deadlock, its just that the main thread is made to wait, and someone should call notify on that object, that someone  could be another non-event or background thread too, so its not a deadlock. In my case, Im sending the main thread in a (kind of)sleep state, where it cannot listen to "anything"..

Comment: if your app does't respond in less than 5 sec, then OS will display a dialog with sorry message, which just says its the unreliable way of doing things. and it is not user friendly and it will frustrate the user. i don't see any need do this.

Comment: you could create an invisible activity above this and catch clicks on it! while pausing the activity behind is paused! When a click occurs you return to the previous activity.. IF this is an answer tell me to post it.. 1 more thing ! To create the empty activity check this http://sherifandroid.blogspot.com/2011/08/creating-global-dialogs.html I already did it

Comment: @ntc I have a requirement to do so and it is triggered/untriggered by User action(click/long click) so user can control it.

Comment: @Sheriff sounds intersting, please give me some time to check it.

Comment: How could it be untriggered by user action (click) if the UI thread will be suspended and won't response to any user interaction?

Comment: @ernazm thats the whole point here. I'm trying to get a workaround for the same thing.

Comment: I think you want to pause some else thread, not UI, coz it sounds a bit senselessly

Comment: What is the matter? What's about a fullscreen custom and transparent view (e.g. as last child in a relative layout) in the foreground which will intercept every touch?! Just trigger it visible and invisible and that's it. No need for a heavy activity. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, *pausing* the activity's main UI thread is not a good idea for various reasons.

It sounds like what you're really looking to do is disable various UI elements instead of *pausing* the activity.  This can be done by calling `setEnabled(boolean)` on the various elements to be disabled/enabled.

When the user clicks the 'pause' button you can go through all the UI elements and disable them (except for the 'unpause' button).  Then when the user clicks the 'unpause' button, you re-enable all the disabled elements.

**Edit:**
If I understand what you're looking for, this is a way to pause and unpause a worker thread.  The worker thread will execute doA() and doB() in the background and can be paused between each of these.  You can add more functions and even a cancel using this method.

```
boolean mIsPaused = false;

final Thread workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      doA();
      checkPause();
      doB();
      checkPause();
      ...
   }
   }
});

private void checkPause() {
   while(isPaused()) {
      // you could also use the notify/wait pattern but that is probably needless complexity for this use case.
      Thread.sleep(50);
   }
}

private synchronized boolean isPaused() {
  return mIsPaused;
}

private synchronized void setPaused(boolean isPaused) {
  mIsPaused = isPaused;
}


pauseButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
      // disable any UI elements that need it
      setIsPaused(true);
   }
});

unPauseButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
      // re-enable any UI elements that need it
      setIsPaused(false);
   }
});
```

Comment: @spatulamnia thanks for the reply but if I just wanted to disable some elements I would have not made this question worth bounty. That would be very simple to do. I do nt want to pause the UI thread either but i do want to achieve the same end result as if UI main thread had paused.take for an example: UI thread is processing following steps: A, B,C Now user does some action in UI when thread is at step B, at this moment i dont want the thread to go to step C and wait until user action.

Comment: ah.  the common way to handle such scenarios is to introduce a *paused* flag into your processing.  When this is set, the thread doing the processing will loop and continue checking this flag effecting a paused state.  Unpausing will set this flag back to its original value allowing normal execution to resume.

Comment: This doesn't pause the thread immediately but allows the thread to reach a 'pausable' state where it can listent for 'unpause' notifications.

Comment: @spatulamnia the problem is How to notify the main thread of unpausing, from the main thread which is waiting itself.the delay i want to add is not absolute where i can sleep for some definite time and wake up, but wake up call is from UI action (such as long click-see the original post above)

Comment: @con_9 What is the problem with using a flag to notify the worker thread that it should continue working?  I've updated my answer to demonstrate how this works.

Answer (score 0):

A silly solution could be this, which is the way to go in embedded system, although this will surely degrade the performance.

```
class App extends Activity
{
private static boolean flag = true;

private void stopthread(){
while(flag){

}

}


private void handleUserEvent(){

//do your stuff and 

flag = false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main thread handles UI events, so if you block it (via a `sleep()`) it ceases to handle the events.

So you can not block the UI thread and expect to unblock it via a user action.